# SKSpriteNode as Return error - Swift 2

Tags: xcode, swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to swap out a basic ball for an image of a ball. I am going through a tutorial and don't know how to fix this. This code is in a file Ball.swift as a function and would like to try avoid redwiring all of the code. Thanks in advance!

Error: Cannot convert return of  the type Ball.Type to return type "Ball"

```
static func make()-> Ball {

    var Ball = SKSpriteNode()

    Ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blueball")
    //let ball = Ball(circleOfRadius: 30)



    Ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: Ball.frame.size.width / 2)
    Ball.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
    Ball.physicsBody!.allowsRotation = true //thi was false
    Ball.userData = NSMutableDictionary()

 //   self.addChild(Ball)
    return self // error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ball` is the name of a variable, and not a type.

The function should return an `SKSpriteNode` which is the class of the ball object. You can also use type inference to avoid having to declare the type. Altogether, it would look like this:

```
static func make() -> SKSpriteNode {

    let ball = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "blueball")

    // Set physics body ...

    return ball
}
```

Tip: Variables are usually named with a lowercase letter, e.g. var ball = ..., and not var Ball = .... This makes it easier to differentiate between variables and types.